# How to get IRC users list over an entire server

Tags: irc

I'm searching for a command like */names*, but on the whole server. Is this possible?

And after that, is it possible to know on which channels a user is connected?

Comment: How is `/names` incorrect? The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_commands#NAMES) seems to indicate doing `/names` without any parameters will list all users on the server organized by channel.

Comment: What client? What server are you connecting to? Do you mean all the rooms on the server too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NAMES` but just omit the `<channel>` and `<server>` variables to get all users.

From [`NAMES` Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_commands#NAMES)

> Returns a list of who is on the comma-separated list of `<channels>`, by channel name. If `<channels>` is omitted, all users are shown, grouped by channel name with all users who are not on a channel being shown as part of channel "*". If `<server>` is specified, the command is sent to `<server>` for evaluation.

You can use the `WHOIS <nick>` command to get information about a specific user.

```
/WHOIS buddy
*** buddy is abcd@dialup-6.provider.com (Think different.)
*** on channels: @#demo #test123
*** on irc via server irc.psinet.com (PSI Net EFNet IRC Server)
```

This will show you what `public` channels a user is on, but not what `secret` channels they may also be connected to.

Note, however, that `NAMES` will not show users that have the `+i` ("invisible") mode set on themselves, *unless* you're also in a channel together with them. Since most networks set `+i` by default, a global `NAMES` will usually show only a few people who have manually set `-i` – not everyone on the network.

Also, on some networks, in particular the *freenode* IRC network, the channel list in `WHOIS` is affected by this mode as well.

Comment: My first attempts to use `/NAMES …` – at `irc.libera.chat`, and at `efnet.port80.se` (apparently the only SSL-capable server for the EU) – failed. For all valid queries, I get: "…  :End of /NAMES list." without listing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works on other IRC servers, but on an *inspircd* server you could do:

```
/stats L
```

You'd probably need to be a server administrator (*oper*) to be allowed to use this command though.

More information:

https://wiki.inspircd.org/Commands

> /STATS [symbol] {server}
>
> Shows various server statistics. Depending on configuration this
> command may be reserved for oper-only use. Note that all /STATS use is
> broadcast to online IRC operators. If a server parameter is given, the
> stats output fromthe servername you provide is returned instead of
> that of the local server.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Error 522 Ray ID: 69faf29adf33736f • 2021-10-17 16:36:46 UTC. Connection timed out"*. The same for just `https://wiki.inspircd.org`.